# How do you add items to the QT QListView

Tags: c++, qt, qlistview

I am creating a mysql reading program and I need to use a QListView with colunms and rows, but I can't work out how.

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use a `QTableView` if you have columns and rows. There is a very good `.PDF` chapter from a Qt book that is actually linked from Qt's own help documentation that covers this. You can get it [here](http://www.phptr.com/content/images/0131872494/samplechapter/blanchette_ch10.pdf).